# Kotlin : Just got back the first parameter from roomdatabase

Tags: android, kotlin, insert, fragment, android-room

i have a problem with my code and i can't solve it .
let just a brief of what i'm going to do : i have a address in the ChooseFragment and there is a edit button for editting the address . ok so far good . the edit click is pass new address to the DatabaseRoom and the address text would be changed . but this is happens just for first time . the secound time the address not changed !! . i know that the insert method work and send the new data to the database room but when i want get it with my query (SELECT * FROM ... ) just show the first parameter and not replace with new value . what is wrong with my codes ?

this is my table :

````
@Entity (tableName = "addresstable")
data class AddressTb(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)```
    val id : Int? ,
    var address: String)```
````

this is my database :

````
@Database(entities = [RoomTables::class , AddressTb::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)


abstract class DataBaseRoom : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun GetDao(): DaoCart


    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: DataBaseRoom? = null

        private val lock = Any()

        operator fun invoke(context: Context) = instance
            ?: synchronized(lock) {
                instance
                    ?: makeDatabase(
                        context
                    ).also {
                        instance = it
                    }
            }

        private fun makeDatabase(context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            DataBaseRoom::class.java,
            "name"
        ).build()
    }

}```
this is my Dao : 
```//address table dao

        @Query("SELECT * FROM addresstable")
        fun getalladress () : LiveData<AddressTb>


        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        suspend fun insertaddress (model : AddressTb)


        @Query("DELETE FROM addresstable")
       suspend fun deleteaddress ()
````

this is my Repository :

```
    fun getalladdress() = db.GetDao().getalladress()

    suspend fun deleteaddress() = db.GetDao().deleteaddress()

    suspend fun insertaddress(model : AddressTb) = db.GetDao().insertaddress(model)
```

this is my Viewmodel :

```
    fun getaddress() = repository.getalladdress()


    fun deleteaddres() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {


        repository.deleteaddress()

    }


    fun insertaddress(model : AddressTb) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {


        repository.insertaddress(model)
```

this is my fragment where i fetch the new insert :

````
class ChosseAddress : Fragment() {


    lateinit var viewModelRoom: ViewModelRoom

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {


        val vl = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_address_layout, container, false)


        val database = DataBaseRoom(requireContext())
        val repository = RepositoryCart(database)
        val factoryRoom = FactoryRoom(repository)


        viewModelRoom =
            ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner { ViewModelStore() }, factoryRoom).get(
                ViewModelRoom::class.java
            )
        viewModelRoom.getaddress().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {


            try {

                vl.txt_address.text = it.address


            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                null
            }

        })



        val animsec: Animation =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(vl.context, R.anim.anim_for_btn_zoom_out)

        vl.button_back_choose_address.setOnClickListener {

            it.startAnimation(animsec)


            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.choose_address_container, HamburgerFragment())
                .commit()

        }

        vl.edit_address.setOnClickListener {


            val mycustomview =
                LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alertfialog_costume, null)
            val dialogtext = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.edit_alert_txt, null)

            val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(mycustomview)
                .setCustomTitle(dialogtext)
            val show = mBuilder.show()

            mycustomview.edit_manually.setOnClickListener {

                show.dismiss()
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.choose_address_container, ManuallyAddressFragment())
                    .commit()


            }


        }



        return vl


    }


}```
````

and this is where i insert data to database :

````
class ManuallyAddressFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var viewmodel: ViewModelRoom

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val layoutview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manually_address_fragment, container, false)

        val database = DataBaseRoom(layoutview.context)
        val repos = RepositoryCart(database)
        val factory = FactoryRoom(repos)

        viewmodel = ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner { viewModelStore },
            factory).get(ViewModelRoom::class.java)


        val btncancle: Button = layoutview.btn_cancle
        val btnsubmit: Button = layoutview.btn_submit_address


        btnsubmit.setOnClickListener {

            val edittext = layoutview.edit_address_manually

            if (edittext.text.toString().isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.submit_btn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {


               val  insert = (AddressTb( null , edittext.text.toString()))
                viewmodel.insertaddress(insert)
                childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(
                        R.anim.anim_fragment_manually,
                        R.anim.anim_fragment_chooseaddress
                    )
                    .replace(R.id.manually_container, ChosseAddress())
                    .commit()
                Toast.makeText(context, "آدرس شما با موفقیت ثبت شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            }


        }



        btncancle.setOnClickListener {

            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.anim.anim_fragment_manually,
                    R.anim.anim_fragment_chooseaddress
                )
                .replace(R.id.manually_container, ChosseAddress())
                .commit()

        }



        return layoutview


    }
}```
````

i tried so things also use update metohd but the database just back the first parameter and i want the new insert value ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the value use the same id, as in your code I see you try to insert new object **AddressTb(null , edittext.text.toString())** you are passing **null** value for **id**, pass the same id from the AddressTb object that you wish to update which you get from getalladdress.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if you're getting all the addresses, it should look like this:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM addresstable")
    fun getalladress () : LiveData<List<AddressTb>>
```

To select a single address, use something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM addresstable WHERE id= :id")
fun findAddressById(id: Long) : AddressTb
```

Comment: no i don't want all of the addresses . i want the new value replace on the old value . somting like update . but update also did'nt workd

Comment: But that function as written makes no sense and won't work. It's called `getAllAddresses`, and the SQLite query selects all the addresses from `addresstable`. So that means it returns a list of `AddressTb` objects.

Comment: so what code should i use to just back the inserted value from my database table ? not all the list

Comment: i edited with your code but don't know what should i pass in here !!!   viewModelRoom.getaddress(???).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {


            try {

                vl.txt_address.text = it.toString()

            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                null
            }

Comment: You pass in the id of the address you want to get. You have a table full of addresses, and the id is a Long that uniquely identifies each address. If you want the first one in the table, use 1.

Comment: But if you're literally just trying to store/edit a single address, I would recommend `SharedPreferences` instead.